# SQLite data should be displayed on view after clicking on tab (view) in tabbedNavigatorApplication (Flex mobile/Flash Builder)

Tags: sqlite, flash-builder4.5

I had created an android app (Employee Directory) in flash builder with SQLite database connection and having 4 tabs (view). I Just want that when I click on the Admin tab the Employee details from the database should be loaded. Below is my code.

**EmployeeDirectory.mxml**

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Style>



    s|ActionBar
    {
        chromeColor: #D3D3D3;

    }

    s|ActionBar #titleDisplay
    {
        color: #161616;
        fontSize: 20;
        fontWeight: normal;
        fontFamily: "Microsoft Sans Serif";
    }

    s|TabbedViewNavigator #tabBar
    {
        chromeColor: #D3D3D3;
        color: #161616;
        fontFamily: "Microsoft Sans Serif";
        iconPlacement:top;

    }



</fx:Style>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            // Switch to the first section in the application.
            tabbedNavigator.selectedIndex = 0;
            // Switch to the first view in the section.
        ViewNavigator(tabbedNavigator.selectedNavigator).popToFirstView();
        }
        protected function BackBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

            // Switch to the first view in the section.
            ViewNavigator(tabbedNavigator.selectedNavigator).popView();
        }   



        ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:navigators>

    <s:ViewNavigator label="Home" width="100%" height="100%"
firstView="views.HomeView" icon="@Embed('assets/Home1.png')">

    </s:ViewNavigator>  
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Admin" width="100%" height="100%" 
firstView="views.AdminView" icon="@Embed('assets/admin.png')">
        <s:navigationContent>
            <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/home.png')"
                      click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/back2.png')"
                      click="BackBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>

        </s:navigationContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Consultants" width="100%" height="100%" 
firstView="views.ConsultantsView" icon="@Embed('assets/doctor.jpg')">
        <s:navigationContent>
            <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/home.png')"
                      click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:navigationContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Extn." width="100%" height="100%" 
firstView="views.ExtnView" icon="@Embed('assets/ext.png')">
        <s:navigationContent>
            <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/home.png')"
                      click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Button label="Back"
                      click="BackBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:navigationContent>
    </s:ViewNavigator>
</s:navigators>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

**AdminView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Admin" xmlns:dao="dao.*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <dao:EmployeeDAO id="srv"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:titleContent>
    <s:TextInput id="key" width="100%"/>
</s:titleContent>
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/search.png')" 
              click="data=srv.findByName(key.text)"/> 
</s:actionContent>
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
        dataProvider="{data}"
        change="navigator.pushView(Employeedetails, list.selectedItem)">
<s:itemRenderer>
<fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer
                label="{data.firstName} {data.lastName}"
                messageField="title"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
</s:View>
```

**EmployeeDAO**

```
package dao
{
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class EmployeeDAO
{
    public function getItem(id:int):Employee
    {
        var sql:String = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName, title, department, 
city, email, officePhone, cellPhone, managerId, picture FROM employee WHERE 
id=?";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;
        stmt.parameters[0] = id;
        stmt.execute();
        var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
        if (result && result.length == 1)
            return processRow(result[0]);
        else
            return null;

    }

    public function findByManager(managerId:int):ArrayCollection
    {
        var sql:String = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE managerId=? ORDER BY 
lastName, firstName";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;
        stmt.parameters[0] = managerId;
        stmt.execute();
        var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
        if (result)
        {
            var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            for (var i:int=0; i<result.length; i++)
            {
                list.addItem(processRow(result[i]));    
            }
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function findByName(searchKey:String):ArrayCollection
    {


         var sql:String = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || 
lastName || ' ' || department LIKE ? and managerId in ('1','2') ORDER BY id, 
managerId, firstName, lastName";
         var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
         stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
         stmt.text = sql;
         stmt.parameters[0] = "%" + searchKey + "%";
         stmt.execute();
         var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
         if (result)
         {
             var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
             for (var i:int=0; i<result.length; i++)
             {
                 list.addItem(processRow(result[i]));   
             }
             return list;
         }
         else
         {
             return null;
         }
    }

    public function create(employee:Employee):void
    {
        trace(employee.firstName);
        if (employee.manager) trace(employee.manager.id);
        var sql:String = 
            "INSERT INTO employee (id, firstName, lastName, title, 
department, managerId, city, officePhone, cellPhone, email, picture) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;
        stmt.parameters[0] = employee.id;
        stmt.parameters[1] = employee.firstName;
        stmt.parameters[2] = employee.lastName;
        stmt.parameters[3] = employee.title;
        stmt.parameters[4] = employee.department;
        stmt.parameters[5] = employee.manager ? employee.manager.id : null;
        stmt.parameters[6] = employee.city;
        stmt.parameters[7] = employee.officePhone;
        stmt.parameters[8] = employee.cellPhone;
        stmt.parameters[9] = employee.email;
        stmt.parameters[10] = employee.picture;
        stmt.execute();
        employee.loaded = true;
    }

    protected function processRow(o:Object):Employee
    {
        var employee:Employee = new Employee();
        employee.id = o.id;
        employee.firstName = o.firstName == null ? "" : o.firstName;
        employee.lastName = o.lastName == null ? "" : o.lastName;
        employee.title = o.title == null ? "" : o.title;
        employee.department = o.department == null ? "" : o.department;
        employee.city = o.city == null ? "" : o.city;
        employee.email = o.email == null ? "" : o.email;
        employee.officePhone = o.officePhone == null ? "" : o.officePhone;
        employee.cellPhone = o.cellPhone == null ? "" : o.cellPhone;
        employee.picture = o.picture;

        if (o.managerId != null)
        {
            var manager:Employee = new Employee();
            manager.id = o.managerId;
            employee.manager = manager;
        }

        employee.loaded = true;
        return employee;
    }
    public static var _sqlConnection:SQLConnection;

    public function get sqlConnection():SQLConnection
    {
        if (_sqlConnection) return _sqlConnection;
        var file:File = 
File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/Employee.db");
        var fileExists:Boolean = file.exists;
        _sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
        _sqlConnection.open(file);
        if (!fileExists)
        {
            createDatabase();
            populateDatabase();
        }
        return _sqlConnection;
    }

    protected function createDatabase():void
    {
        var sql:String = 
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( "+
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "firstName VARCHAR(50), " +
            "lastName VARCHAR(50), " +
            "title VARCHAR(50), " +
            "department VARCHAR(50), " + 
            "managerId INTEGER, " +
            "city VARCHAR(50), " +
            "officePhone VARCHAR(30), " + 
            "cellPhone VARCHAR(30), " +
            "email VARCHAR(30), " +
            "picture VARCHAR(200))";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;
        stmt.execute();         
    }

    protected function populateDatabase():void
    {
        var file:File = 
File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/employees.xml");
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        var xml:XML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
        stream.close();
        var employeeDAO:EmployeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
        for each (var emp:XML in xml.employee)
        {
            var employee:Employee = new Employee();
            employee.id = emp.id;
            employee.firstName = emp.firstName;
            employee.lastName = emp.lastName;
            employee.title = emp.title;
            employee.department = emp.department;
            employee.city = emp.city;
            employee.officePhone = emp.officePhone;
            employee.cellPhone = emp.cellPhone;
            employee.email = emp.email;
            employee.picture = emp.picture;
            if (emp.managerId>0)
            {
                employee.manager = new Employee();
                employee.manager.id = emp.managerId;
            }
            employeeDAO.create(employee);
        }
    }


}
}
```

The below is my screen

[this is the home screen and after clicking on admin tab the data should be 
   displayed. Currently the data is displayed after clicking on search button in 
   admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjKo3.jpg)

[After clicking on admin tab from home screen][2]

[The data should be displayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Iw7.jpg)

Comment: Edited your question to fit tags and wording for SQLite. Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)